# ASP.NET MVC Авторизация

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

В общем создал дефолтный проект, где уже есть контекст, модели и тд. Решил подправить регистрацию и авторизацию. Пока что сумел отключить регистрацию по емэйлу (сделал по имени пользователя).

Но при этом все равно в базу пишется имя пользователя не только в поле `UserName`, но и в `Email`. Почему?

Еще я хочу сделать следующее. Мне нужно при первом входе (когда нет ни одного пользователя) запросить регистрацию администратора, а остальных пользователей должен создавать именно администратор. Как это сделать?

или дайте ссылку на хорошую книжку (на русском) на ASP MVC 5

Comment: если Вы используете [tag:asp.net-identity] то советую обратить внимание вот на этот `nuget` [пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples)

Answer (score 0):

Ну тогда делаем примерно так

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string message = "",int? hasError = 0, string ReturnUrl = "/")
    {
        try
        {
            var connstate = FFIUserConnection.CheckConnectionState(message);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (connstate == 5)
            {
                //если под нами где-то зашли и мы вызвали паршл, то не сможем вернуться после логина назад, а только на главную страницу
                return Content("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=/Account/Login?message='"+ message + " />");
            }
            else
            {
                    return Content("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0' />");
            }
        }

         //   LogOffAction();
            if (hasError == 1)
            {
                ViewBag.hasError = hasError;
                ViewBag.message = ((Exception)Session["unhandledException"]).Message;
            }

            if (connstate == 5)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Под вашим пользователем произошла авторизация на другой машине");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }


        return View();
    }
```

где FFIUserConnection.CheckConnectionState

есть класс для проверки всех твоих условий...

Ну и...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(AuthenticateModel model, string ReturnUrl = "/")
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session["ENDTIME"] = null; 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Login))
            {
                var usercon = new FFIUserConnection(model.Login, string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) ?"":model.Password);
                if (usercon.UserId > 0)
                {
                    var authCookie = usercon.StartSession(Request,User);
                    if (authCookie != null)
                    {

                        Response.Cookies.Remove(authCookie.Name);
                        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
                       Response.Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                        Session["CURUser"] = null;

                       if (CheckBrowser(usercon.Browser, usercon.BrowserVersion) == 1)
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("UpgradeBrowser", "Account", new { url = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.Login, true) });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (model.Password == "123456")
                            {
                                Session["pswrdchange"] = true;
                            }
                            return View();
                        }

                    } else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ошибка при авторизации");
                   }

                } else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Не верный логин или пароль");
                }
            } else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Необходимо указать пользователя");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: попробую вечером

Answer (score -2):

Как это ни одного пользователя!? Кто то все равно должен быть. Делается это примерно так. Вводится пользователь "Администратор" с паролем "123456". И при первом входе вываливается такая форма "Вы вошли с дефолтным паролем для продолжения работы нужно изменить пароль!!". Ну или что-то в этом роде...

Comment: [ссылка на статью про авторизацию](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.1.php)

Comment: Ну как. Вот так вот. Если пользователей нет в базе, должно выводиться окно регистрации для админа. В чем проблема с точки зрения логики я не знаю. Вопрос только в реализации

Comment: А статья ровным счетом ничего не дает. Она говорит что делать, но не объясняет как все это работает. Шаг влево/вправо уже сделать проблематично.

Comment: Хорошо! Тогда надо делать свою авторизацию и свои таблички ролей и т. д. Я думаю в MVC все это реализуемо...